# Show 5 div on page scroll in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 10 divs in my page. 1st div is visible and others are hidden.

```
div1,div2,div3----div10
```

On page scroll I want to show 5 div.

```
div2----div6
div7---div12 (div12 not exist. I know but just want to show you limit)
```

and on second time page scroll I want to show **5 div** again and it will happen again if there are more than **10 divs**.

```
total_data = 10
limit= 5
....Page scroll code comes here.....
for(i =1; i<=limit; i++)
div show i;
total_data= total_data +1
}
```

Please don't be afraid about the typos, I am only looking for logic. I will write the clean code.

Comment: @Vucko Thank you. I will take a look of the question which you have mentioned.

Comment: I checked that question but i don't think its relevant. I am simply looking for  loop and question was about DOM element.

Comment: Than I misunderstood the OP. Retracting the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way (like you asked this is just idea for the code):

```
var scrollTimes = 0; 
$('body').on('scroll',function(){
 scrollTimes++; //also add if statement when the scroll times reaches maximum to restart
 var limit = scrollTimes + 5;
 for(i = scrollTimes; i<=limit; i++)
   var x = i+5;
   div show x; //example $('#div' + x).show();
 } 
});
```

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested any of it. But I hope you get the gist of it. I came up with something along those lines.

```
var arrayOfDivs = $(".divs"); // divs to appear/disappear
var currentlyShownDivs = 1; // shown divs upon loading page
//optionally make the code more flexible by adding a variable for the no of divs to show.

$(body).scroll(function(){
//if function to detect scrollup or scrolldown
    //on scrolldown
    arrayOfDivs.hide();
    for(i=0; i<5 ;i++){
        if(i+currentlyShownDivs > arrayOfDivs.length){//stop code when scrolling too far
            break;
        }
        if(i+currentlyShownDivs < arrayOfDivs.length){ //don't run the code if divs to display do not exist
            arrayOfDivs.eq(i+currentlyShownDivs).show(); // show the next 5 divs one by one
        }
        if(i+currentlyShownDivs = arrayOfDivs.length || i=4){
            currentlyShownDivs += 5;//one time increment to enable the code to run for the next 5 divs.
        }
    }
    //on scrollup
        //simular code to do the opposite from scrolldown.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up